# Largest integer to divide all products of $n$ consecutive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the largest integer guaranteed to divide all products of $n$ consecutive integers.

I started by looking at small values of $n$. I logically assumed that it should be $n!$. But I couldn't express it mathematically.

Answer (score 3):

The largest integer that divides the product $(1)(2)(3)\cdots (n)$ is $n!$.

Now we show that $n!$ divides the product of any $n$ consecutive integers. It is enough to deal with consecutive *positive* integers.

One can give a proof  by induction. However, to me a *combinatorial proof* is more satisfying. The number of ways to choose $n$ objects from $N$ is the integer $\binom{N}{n}$. We have
$$\binom{N}{n}=\frac{(N)(N-1)\cdots (N-n+1)}{n!}.$$
It follows that $n!$ divides the product $(N)(N-1)\cdots (N-n+1)$ of $n$ consecutive integers for any $N\ge n$.

Comment: we suspect this guy is asking from a current examination.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164122/find-all-the-integer-solutions-of-the-following-diophantine-equations

Comment: Homework, likely, that fits a high proportion of questions. Exam, presumably not in North America, timing is off.

Comment: This doesn't quite prove that $n!$ is the largest though?

Comment: The "largest" part is dealt with in the first sentence of the answer. Certainly $n!$ is the largest integer that divides $n!$.